# Is it possible to specify the timing function of a CAAnimation with a quadratic bezier curve?

Tags: ios, core-animation, bezier

I know it is possible to specify the timing function of a CAAnimation with a cubic bezier curve using:

[CAMediaTimingFunction](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CAMediaTimingFunction_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

But, is it possible to specify the timing function with a quadratic bezier curve?

Why I want this?, you may ask. Well, is either that or concatenate a couple of animations in order to achieve the motion path I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Any Bézier curve can be exactly represented by another Bézier curve of a higher degree in a process called degree elevation. Wikipedia [has a nice overview](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Degree_elevation) of the method with an example of elevating a quadratic to cubic Bézier curve.

Assuming the control point of quadratic curve fits inside [0, 1] box the corresponding cubic curve should be representable as a `CAMediaTimingFunction`.